# SerialPort received data lost at high baudrates when stream contains 0x1A

Tags: c#, serial-port, eof, data-loss, baud-rate

I am implementing a C# application which reads binary data from a microcontroller at a high baudrate (8 MegaBaud) using an USB-Serial adapter (FTDI FT232H). The problem is when the stream contains 0x1A, sometimes a big chunk of data (thousands of bytes) is lost after this byte.

I found on the forums that 0x1A is a special character (EOFCHAR) and Windows is doing a special handling for this. However [this solution](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0e8cb6e2-077e-45a4-b01c-2eddb831c864/serialport-0x1a-character-reading-problem) of decompiling `SerialStream` and changing `EOFCHAR` to another byte value doesn't help me, I need to use the entire byte range (0..255).

I created a small test application to reproduce my problem, sending repeatedly the same byte, using 2 serial adapters connected to the same computer and FT232R-TX connected to FT232H-RX

```
using System;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace SerialPort_0x1A_Loss_Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const byte BYTE_FILL = 0x1A;    // 0x1A is EOFCHAR
            const int  BAUD_RATE = 3000000; // 3 MegaBaud
            const int  BUFF_SIZE = 1000000;

            SerialPort sp1_FT232R = 
               new SerialPort("COM3", BAUD_RATE, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
            SerialPort sp2_FT232H = 
               new SerialPort("COM6", BAUD_RATE, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);

            sp1_FT232R.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
            sp1_FT232R.WriteBufferSize        = 20000000;
            sp1_FT232R.Open();

            sp2_FT232H.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
            sp2_FT232H.ReadBufferSize         = 20000000;
            sp2_FT232H.ReceivedBytesThreshold = 20000000;
            sp2_FT232H.Open();

            byte[] bufferTx = new byte[BUFF_SIZE];
            for (int i = 0; i < BUFF_SIZE; i++)
            {
                bufferTx[i] = BYTE_FILL;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Sending ...");
            sp1_FT232R.Write(bufferTx, 0, BUFF_SIZE);
            Console.WriteLine("Sending finished. " +
                "Press a key to view status, ESC to exit.");

            // Receiving maybe not yet finished, 
            // query the status with a keypress
            while (Console.ReadKey(true).Key != ConsoleKey.Escape)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("TOTAL RX = " + sp2_FT232H.BytesToRead);
            }

            // A second test, using .Read() call
            // This will be executed after pressing ESC for the previous test
            int totalRX_Read_Call = 0;
            var listBufferRx = new List<byte>();
            int btr; // BytesToRead
            while ( (btr = sp2_FT232H.BytesToRead) > 0)
            {
                var bufferRx = new byte[btr];
                totalRX_Read_Call += sp2_FT232H.Read(bufferRx, 0, btr);
                listBufferRx.AddRange(bufferRx);
                Console.WriteLine("totalRX_Read_Call = " + totalRX_Read_Call + 
                    ";  listBufferRx.Count = " + listBufferRx.Count);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();

            sp1_FT232R.Close();
            sp2_FT232H.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Test results (BUFF_SIZE = 1000000 for all tests):

```
1.  BYTE_FILL = 0x55; BAUD_RATE = 3000000; TOTAL RX = 1000000 ( no loss)
2.  BYTE_FILL = 0x1A; BAUD_RATE = 3000000; TOTAL RX =  333529 (66% loss)
3.  BYTE_FILL = 0x1A; BAUD_RATE = 2000000; TOTAL RX =  627222 (37% loss)
4.  BYTE_FILL = 0x1A; BAUD_RATE = 1000000; TOTAL RX = 1000000 ( no loss)
```

Also, the load on the CPU (i7-4770k at 4 GHz) is high (over 30%) for tests like 2, 3, 4, but low (3%) for test 1. For test 1, I tried with all other patterns for a byte (0x00..0x19, 0x1B..0xFF) and there is no loss.

Do you know if there is a solution for this?
Thank you very much!

Comment: This test is meaningless if you don't actually call Read().  You'll very rarely get *all* of the data with a single Read() call, just whatever is present in the receive buffer.  Less if it contains a 0x1a byte.  If you use the DataReceived event then be sure to not ignore the e.EventType property.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for the reply, I edited my question's code, adding a test with Read(), and the results are the same. Also, in my application, I use the DataReceived event and I tried to return when `e.EventType == SerialData.Eof` but the problem with 0x1A data loss is never solved. At 8 MBaud, when I send only 0x1A, I receive only about 5% of what I'm transmitting.

Comment: I would try this with all 8-bit patterns to see which ones have the problem. If it's *just* `1A`, it may be a software problem. Otherwise it's probably that the hardware can't handle it.

Comment: @Gabe I tried with all patterns, the problem I'm describing is only for `1A` and only at high baudrates (I also edited my post to add this info). I'm sure the problem it's from SerialPort class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, I can't explain why receiving that character would cause bytes to be lost. While you might think the problem is setting the EOF character, that doesn't quite make sense.

The [documentation for the `DCB` (device control block) structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363214(v=vs.85).aspx) indicates that `EofChar` is "The value of the character used to signal the end of data", but does not say what that means. There is no other reference to the mysterious `EofChar` anywhere else that I can find. Furthermore, the same page says this about the `fBinary` member: "If this member is TRUE, binary mode is enabled. Windows does not support nonbinary mode transfers, so this member must be TRUE."

What's the connection? Well, [kb101419](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/101419) states how it used to work in 16-bit Windows:

```
    fBinary - If fBinary is set to zero, reception of the EofChar
        character indicates the end of the input stream. ReadComm()
        will not return any characters past EofChar. If any characters
        are received after EofChar, it will be treated as overflowing
        the receive queue (CE_RXOVER). The reception of EofChar is
        indicated in the COMSTAT status flag CSTF_EOF. If fBinary is
        set to one, the EofChar character has no special meaning.
```

In other words, the `EofChar` is only used when `fBinary` is zero, yet Windows no longer supports that mode, thus it seems that `EofChar` is ignored.

So what is causing `0x1A` to be treated as a special character? The DCB has another member called `EvtChar`, defined as `The value of the character used to signal an event`. When this character is received on the port, the port's event is signaled and the `EV_RXFLAG` bit is set for that port. The `SerialData` enum defines `Eof = NativeMethods.EV_RXFLAG`, which is why there is some confusion as to what EOF means.

OK, but that doesn't explain why that character causes data loss. I couldn't find any documentation about it, but my guess is that when the `EvtChar` is received on the port, the event is signaled and no more data is buffered until that event is cleared. At low data rates the event is cleared before another byte is received, so nobody ever noticed the problem before. At high data rates, potentially thousands of bytes may be received during this period. And if this is actually an aspect of the serial port driver, the behavior may be hard to reproduce on other systems.

Now the problem is how to disable this behavior. The `SerialStream` class always sets the `EvtChar` to `0x1A`, but that doesn't matter because changing it to a different byte just moves the problem rather than fixing it. I believe the actual problem is caused by calling [SetCommMask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363435(v=vs.85).aspx) with the `EV_RXFLAG` bit (`0x0002`) set. Unfortunately this flag is always set regardless of whether you are listening on the event, meaning that the driver will always need to signal it.

I suspect that you can solve your problem by calling `SetCommMask` with that bit cleared. The default for `SerialStream` is `0x1fb` (all bits but `EV_TXEMPTY`). Since `EV_RXFLAG` is `0x002`, you can pass in `0x1F9` to clear it.

The P/Invoke signature for `SetCommMask` is:

```
using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true, CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern bool SetCommMask(
        SafeFileHandle hFile, 
        int dwEvtMask 
    );
```

To get the `hFile` you will have to use Reflection to get the `_handle` field of `sp1_FT232R.BaseStream`:

```
var _handle = (SafeFileHandle)sp1_FT232R.BaseStream.GetType()
              .GetField("_handle", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
              .GetValue(sp1_FT232R.BaseStream);
SetCommMask(_handle, 0x1F9);
```

Comment: This solved the problem! Just now I tested on the real system by sending over 100MB of `0x1A` alone and also by sweeping between `0x00` and `0xFF` and no byte is lost! I inserted the above call after `serialPort1.Open();`  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using a different encoder. I like to use the windows-1252 encoder as I handle small (100 byte) datastreams from 8bit MCUs frequently.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa332096(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: I just edited my post by setting the Encoding to Windows-1252. Tested on hardware and the problem is still there (only when sending 0x1A at high baudrates).